# Can I implement word prediction with JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need advice, is there any way to implement with JComboBox word prediction, when I start type I want to open dropdown with all words which start with part what I typed ?
Or I need to use some other component, which one ? Please help, I read documentation but I couldn't find what I need.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at this article: [AutoComplete JComboBox](http://tech.chitgoks.com/2009/11/06/autocomplete-jcombobox/) or google on autocompletion and JCombobox. There are several libraries that are solving the problem.